# MathJax-how can I used it in the Github pages?

Tags: mathjax, github-pages

I cannot use mathjax in MarkDown page as described [here](http://hypergroups.github.io/2013/08/27/MathJax-MarkDown-Test.html) and [here](http://hypergroups.github.io/2013/08/27/MathJax-Test.html). I would like to know how to do that?

I can use mathjax in html files now.

It seems that mathjax cannot render the $$ displayformula?

Comment: Both links are dead now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually *do* have MathJax working with the first page that you cite (the other link seems to be broken).  If you notice the first equation, it has been typeset by MathJax (note that its contextual menu is MathJax's).  The problem is that Markdown is turning your underscores into `<em>` tags, and that means MathJax won't process those equations (MathJax doesn't process math that contains HTML tags).

One solution is to put spaces around your underscores, so that Markdown will ignore them.

Another would be to use backticks (`` ` ``) around the math to turn it into "verbatim" mode, so Markdown won't modify its contents.  That may cause the math to be enclosed in `<code>` tags, which MathJax will ignore.  So you would need to modify your configuration to include

```
tex2jax: {
  skipTags: ["script","noscript","style","textarea","pre"]
}
```

(the default has `"code"` in that list) so that MathJax will process the contents of `<code>` tags.

**Addition**:

Your theme styles code blocks with white text on black backgrounds, so you may want to add some additional CSS to set that back.  You may be able to do that somewhere in your theme controls, but you could also add

```
styles: {
  code: {
    "font-family": "inherit",
    "color": "inherit!important",
    "background": "inherit!important"
  }
}
```

to your MathJax configuration, and it will set the styles for you.  Note that this will also modify how *any* backticked material will show up.  If you want to have it only affect MathJax output, that would take more work.

Comment: http://hypergroups.github.io/2013/08/27/MathJax-MarkDown-Test.html

Use backticks like this?

Comment: No, you need to put the backticks *outside* the dollar signs, not inside.  I see that the theme you are using also inverts the colors for code blocks.  I've modified my answer above to explain one way to work around that.

Comment: Though I haven's succeed now, I found one possible problem.When I include `tex2jax: {
  skipTags: ["script","noscript","style","textarea","pre"]
}`, then seems I cannot render latex in the html files.

Comment: Make sure that you have the commas correct in your `MathJax.Hub.Config` call.  There should be commas between the different blocks in the configuration (so check that there is one after the brace following the `tex2jax` block, before the next block).   Make sure there are no *extra* commas (there should not be any commas followed by directly close braces, even if the brace is on a different line).  Your links are no longer working, so I can't check to see what you have used myself.